# Kendo Datasource.Data() equals Datasource.View()

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, datasource

I've been working with Kendo UI for some time now and I've stumble upon behaviour I can't explain

When you visit http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding on grid you can see total of 830 elements.

When you go to console and run

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.view()
```

You receive array of 20 elements (as expected). And when you run

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()
```

You receive array of the same 20 elements. I tried playing with filters and from my experience .data() behaves exactly the same as view(), which is odd. As far as I understand documentation I should receive 20 elements when using view(), but i should receive all 830 when using data()

Have I been doing something wrong? Does data filter elements (and paginate) on backend? For reference this is my backend method, which returns data for my grid

```
public ActionResult IndexDataSource([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var customers = this.GetViewModel();
    return this.Json(customers.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicity setting .ServerOperation(false) in MVC syntax resolved problem. I would like to thank j4ro for pointing me this option.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
      {
          ...
      })
  .Sortable()
  .Filterable()
  .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
  .Events(e => e.DataBound("CustomerGridDataBound"))
  .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(new[] { 5, 50, 200, 99999 })
            .ButtonCount(5))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(5)
            .ServerOperation(false)   // you need to add this to be able to use .data()
            .Read(read => read.Action("ActionDataSource", "Controller"))

  ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in this example the serverFiltering property is set to true (and serverPaging, serverSorting also). So on the javaScript side, you will always have same data whatever you're using view() or data() method. And it will be the same array what controller's acton returns to display: one, selected page.
To make view() works as documentation say you have to turn off all properties that i said and read whole data in one bunch.

Comment: It's true for javascript based code, but I'm using MVC syntax, and it's not set there. I will try to explicity set this to false, and check if this will help

Comment: It should work the same way (with a strong focus to 'should') . MVC just generate javascript code by C# snipped and render components same way. You in JS you can only access the data you've read first by controller, and server filtering forces pageable grid to read each page separetly. Grid's data source will not ask the controller for any other data when data() or view() method is used.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This option is set to true by default, and It will behave correctly if I set it explicitly